# CURL not working from php

Tags: php, curl, commercetools

In my app, I'm using the Commercetools API.

To get data from their API I need to call an endpoint.

Following is the endpoint I used to get products.

```
https://api.sphere.io/vc-1209/products -H "Authorization: Bearer -5DVqQFgkd_SDGthsFgtepS"
```

When I run above URL in terminal like

```
curl https://api.sphere.io/vc-1209/products -H "Authorization: Bearer -5DVqQFgkd_SDGthsFgtepS"
```

It's giving me a response with all the products.

But when I execute the same URL from PHP's cURL it's not working.

```
$url = 'https://api.sphere.io/vc-1209/products -H "Authorization: Bearer -5DVqQFgkd_SDGthsFgtepS"';

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

print_r($response);
```

I'm getting back:

> Client sent a bad request.

Comment: Your variable is called url and you pass... something that is not an URL. Doesn't that make you think where the error could be?

Comment: GET or POST? Because in the php script you have a POST

Answer (score 5):

You of all you need to set `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` here in your example, than you can get the response.

```
<?php
$url = 'https://api.sphere.io/vc-1209/products';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
      'Authorization: Bearer -5DVqQFgkd_SDGthsFgtepS'
      ));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

When you run your code in local host, it will give you `bool(false)` maybe just because of `https` request.

When i hit your request on production where https enabled, it gives me this response:

> string(130)
>   "{"statusCode":401,"message":"invalid_token","errors":[{"code":"invalid_token","message":"invalid_token"}],"error":"invalid_token"}"

This error clearly show, you need to add `access token` in your CURL request as a header.

Also note that, curl status code is 401 which means, you are not authorized to execute this request you must need to add access token.

Comment: and also for downvoter, atleast wait for 10 to 15 seconds if you dont want to share comments or improvement areas

Comment: I think when a user downvotes they should be forced to give a reason...I'll upvote you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is obvious, you are adding the `-H "Authorization: Bearer -5DVqQFgkd_SDGthsFgtepS"` to the URL, which will cause PHP to request the URL:

> https://api.sphere.io/vc-1209/products%20-H%22Authorization%3A%20Bearer%20-5DVqQFgkd_SDGthsFgtepS%22

If you want to set custom headers in PHP's cURL set the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS` option:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://api.sphere.io/vc-1209/products');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( // Set Headers
    'Authorization: Bearer -5DVqQFgkd_SDGthsFgtepS'
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
print_r($response);
curl_close($curl); // Close cURL
```

Comment: Tried stll same

Comment: @Gowri Have you changed the URL as well?

Comment: this is authrization issue, you need to add access token in your request..

Comment: Yes I had changed

Comment: @devpro Bearer is the access token. Ofcouse I mentioned accesstoken in  my script is worong. I don't want to share my key to public.

Comment: @Gowri then it should do **exactly** what you are doing in your cURL request.

Comment: @TimSpeckhals: i think OP got the solution :) my vote for u

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the headers appropriately:

```
$url = 'https://api.sphere.io/vc-1209/products';
$bearerToken = "someToken";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer '.$bearerToken));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```